# SQL Pivot table?

Tags: sql

Hi I am looking for a SQL Script the can pivot the following table
[image]

Every values in ObjectClassProperty column must become columns. ObjectInstanceProperty will become values for the respectivly newly created column.

One thing to keep in mind. ObjectClass is dynamically changing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented once such similar solution in MS SQL Server 2019 version.
Details can be found in the [dbfiddle<>example<>dynamicpivot](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ae69f8b1dbc36935cf6cc23884e3ff3e).

*Note: This will work if there are not duplicates in ObjectClassProperty.*